# "XXXX_Datacatalog" and "XXXX_Datacatlog_viewer" of file's connection source in WKC

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog

I noticed that files in the WKC have two different sources of connection in their property. One is the Connection name of COS, like AAAAA_Datacatalog, and the other is almost the same but with "_viewer" behind, like "AAAAA_Datacatlog_viewer".What kind of condition will cause this difference? Are these two kind of files behave different in WKC?

Answer (score 0):

The files stored in IBM Cloud Object Storage (COS) reflects which connection it came from.  By default, we create two system COS connections for you as part of the Catalog.  One has editor rights which is the first one and the other one has viewer rights.  Based on how you add assets later on and which connection you use, it will appear under the path of that connection object.